# How to call an onscroll function from an window.innerWidth - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call my scroller function only when window width is >599 and the user is scrolling. The function works just fine on its own when scrolling, but when i add the event listener the function does not work. Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

```
//only run scroller is window size is > 599
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
  if(window.innerWidth > 599){
    window.onscroll = function() {scroller()}
  }
};  

const scroller = () => {
  //PROGRESS SCROLL BAR
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("scrollBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";

  //COLLAPSE HEADER WHEN SCROLLING
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    document.querySelector("header").style.height = "5rem";
    document.querySelector("h1").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("nav ul").style.top = "1rem";
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.marginTop = "10rem";
    document.getElementById("scrollContainer").style.top = "5rem";
    document.getElementById("scrollBar").style.top = "5rem";
  } else {
    document.querySelector("header").style.height = "15rem";
    document.querySelector("h1").style.display = "inherit";
    document.querySelector("nav ul").style.top = "3rem";
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.marginTop = "15rem";
    document.getElementById("scrollContainer").style.top = "inherit";
    document.getElementById("scrollBar").style.top = "inherit";
  } 
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just check the `innerWidth` inside the event handler.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 599) scroller();
});
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thankyou

Comment: @Jordan Glad to help.